# asp.net core 2.2 web api "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found" error Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

The configuration looks ok. but i get the error while trying to add Azure AD based authentication.

`Startup.cs => ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    // Rest of the code
}
```

`Startup.cs => Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IMicrosoftServersHealthCheckService microsoftServersHealthCheckService)
{
    _logger.LogTrace($"Inside Configure for Environment: {Environment.EnvironmentName}");
            
    app.UseMiddleware<APIResponseMiddleware>();
    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
    {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var exception = errorFeature.Error;
            _logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
            ExceptionHandlerFilter.HandleExceptionAsync(context, exception).Wait();
        });
    });
    
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // The following will be picked up by Application Insights.
        _logger.LogInformation("Configuring for Development environment");
        //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
    }
    else
    {
        // The following will be picked up by Application Insights.
        _logger.LogInformation($"Configuring for {Environment.EnvironmentName} environment");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        //app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DNS API");

    });

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
    
}
```

`Message: "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."`

`Stack Trace: System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure AD to project your web API, please refer to the following code

1. Install the package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Web -Version 1.6.0
```

2. Code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // more code
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    // more code
}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration)

Comment: My application is using asp.net core version 2.2 will this package Microsoft.Identity.Web work with a 2.2 api application? one of the prerequisites in the first link you shared specifies .NET Core SDK 3.1. Does this requirement mean that i need to install the SDK on the IIS server or does it mean it will work on an application that is built using .net core  3.1 or later? Kindly clarify!

Comment: @blogs4t The package `Microsoft.Identity.Web` need net ore 3.1 or later : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web/1.6.0. If you use net core 2.2, please refer to https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/12/walkthrough-how-to-protect-an-asp-net-core-web-api-application-with-azure-ad/